# Using the text in a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, text-files

I am making a speech dictation program and I was wondering how I could get all the words I have listed in a text file so I can check against it?

My text file is setup like this:

> alpha
>   bravo
>   charlie
>   delta

Comment: Speech dictation, so you want to ensure that all words in the file are understood by your app or are you doing TTS and you just want the app to read the words in the file?

Answer (score 3):

This gives you an array of the lines in the text file. Just change the path to point at your file.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Greg is 100% correct and will do exactly what you are asking, based on what you are saying about making a speech dictation program, I might suggest looking into the SRGS XML Grammar syntax.  If you are programming for Windows, which according to your `C#` you most likely are, then there are built in APIs that you can then feed this XML file to make a speech enabled application.

Check out [MSDN - Create Grammars Using XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361594%28v=office.14%29.aspx)